# Avoid getting slf4j from maven

Tags: java, maven, jetty, slf4j

Maven uses slf4j, so as soon as it is launched, it initializes it with its default implementation contained into apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar and with configuration file defined in apache-maven-3.3.9\conf\logging\simplelogger.properties.

After that it loads the pom file and found my jetty-maven-plugin which launch a webapp. But in this webapp I want to use a different implementation for slf4j, but I can't because slf4j is already initialized.

I understand that maven is mainly a tool for build and not to launch apps, but I can't modify log configuration of apache-maven for each project to get pretty logs for each of them.

Is someone already face this issue and find a way to avoid that?

Note:

- run-forked instead run works but in this case I can't no more debug from eclipse so I prefer an another solution.
- older version of maven works as 3.0.3 because it didn't used slf4j